# How to maximise TextFormField in a Dialog/Form with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-alertdialog, flutter-textformfield

I have a Dialog/Form like this (Flutter 3.0.5 - Web Chrome):

```
Future<void> showInformationDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
            return AlertDialog(
              insetPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              content: Row(children: [
                SizedBox(
                    width: screenWidth * 0.6,
                    height: screenHeight * 0.5,
                    child: Form(
                      key: _formKey,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          TextFormField(
                            controller: _titleEditingController,
                            validator: (value) {
                              return value!.isNotEmpty ? null : "Title";
                            },
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: "Title"),
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                child:
                                    TextField(
                                      enabled: false,
                                      controller: _dateController,
                                    ),
                              ),
                              ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  _restorableDatePickerRouteFuture.present();
                                },
                                child: const Icon(Icons.calendar_month),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                child:
                                TextField(
                                  enabled: false,
                                  controller: _timeController,
                                ),
                              ),
                              ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  _displayTimeDialog();
                                },
                                child: const Icon(Icons.access_time_outlined),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 30,),
                          TextFormField(
                            controller: _detailsEditingController,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                            maxLines: null,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                hintText: "Enter Task Details",
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2)
                                ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                  )))]),
              title: const Text('Create Task'),
              actions: <Widget>[
                InkWell(
                  child: const Text('OK'),
                  onTap: () {
                    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          });
        });
  }
```

and I have added a percentage width/height to it. However the `TextFormField` does not fill the whole available space automatically (image below), and you can only predefine the number of lines which won't work for all cases. How can I make the `TextFormField` able to fill the available space?

[image]

If I add what Yeasin suggests in his solution, I get:

> The hitTest() method was called on this RenderBox: RenderConstrainedBox#c7750 relayoutBoundary=up1:
> needs compositing
> creator: ConstrainedBox ← Align ← MediaQuery ← Padding ← AnimatedPadding ← Dialog ← AlertDialog ← StatefulBuilder ← Builder ← DefaultTextStyle ← *CaptureAll ← MediaQuery ← ⋯
> parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
> constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=1491.0, 0.0<=h<=1311.0)
> size: MISSING
> additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(280.0<=w<=Infinity, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
> Although this node is not marked as needing layout, its size is not set.
> A RenderBox object must have an explicit size before it can be hit-tested. Make sure that the RenderBox in question sets its size during layout.
> at Object.throw* [as throw] (http://localhost:38447/dart_sdk.js:5080:11)

Comment: Can you include an image and point the issue or attached an image that you are trying to archive

Comment: I have attached an image

Comment: You want last TextFiled to fill the height , this is the only thing is missing here ?

Comment: Yes, well the OK on the bottom atm is not well placed in the padding, but yes that is the main problem.

Comment: BTW `expands: true` will make the widget fail with error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Expanded` with `maxLines:null` and `expands: true,`

```dart
Expanded(
    child: TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  expands: true,
  maxLines: null,
  minLines: null,
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    hintText: "Enter Task Details",
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2),
    ),
  ),
)),
```

[image]

Full dialog

```dart
  Future<void> showInformationDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
            return AlertDialog(
              insetPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              content: Row(children: [
                SizedBox(
                  // color: Colors.cyanAccent.withOpacity(.3),
                  width: screenWidth * 0.6,
                  height: screenHeight * 0.5,
                  child: Form(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: [
                        TextFormField(
                          validator: (value) {
                            return value!.isNotEmpty ? null : "Title";
                          },
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: "Title"),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: TextField(
                                enabled: false,
                              ),
                            ),
                            ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              child: const Icon(Icons.calendar_month),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: TextField(
                                enabled: false,
                              ),
                            ),
                            ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              child: const Icon(Icons.access_time_outlined),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 30,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                            child: TextFormField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                          expands: true,
                          maxLines: null,
                          minLines: null,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "Enter Task Details",
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ]),
              title: const Text('Create Task'),
              actions: <Widget>[
                InkWell(
                  child: const Text('OK'),
                  onTap: () {},
                ),
              ],
            );
          });
        });
  }
```

Comment: I already tried that way but I get this error: `The hitTest() method was called on this RenderBox: RenderConstrainedBox#c7750 relayoutBoundary=up1:
  needs compositing
  creator: ConstrainedBox ← Align ← MediaQuery ← Padding ← AnimatedPadding ← Dialog ← AlertDialog ← StatefulBuilder ← Builder ← DefaultTextStyle ← _CaptureAll ← MediaQuery ← ⋯
  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=1491.0, 0.0<=h<=1311.0)
  size: MISSING
  `

Comment: can try try flutter clean and rebuild the app. Also I am checking If i;ve changed more

Comment: Try to run full dialog snippet

Comment: Just tried clean and re-run but same issue

Comment: My tested device is chrome,

Comment: works thanks! Sorry I missed the `Expanded` on top

Comment: It's ok, things happen. Also you can use `LayoutBuilder` as a child of `Expanded` and then use its constrains

Comment: do you get the cursor in the middle too? From your image looks so

Comment: yap, I think so

Comment: `child: TextFormField(textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical(y: -1.0),....` seems to fix it

Comment: You can also use `textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,` or `top` depends on your need